# Call to undefined relationship [loanRequest] on model [App\Models\Employee]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i m getting this error while running employee model with loan its keep throwing this message Call to undefined relationship [loanRequest] on model [App\Models\Employee]. what problem there ?

```
class Employee extends Model{
    public function loan() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LoanRequest');
    }
}

class LoanRequest extends Model{
    public function employee(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Employee');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you try to get loan from employee ?

Comment: Share the code block where you are getting this error.

Comment: solved it by modifying the code like Employee::with('loan')->get();

Answer (score 1):

In your blade view, the way you access the loan request through employee relation is by

```
<?php
    foreach($employees as $employee){
        foreach($employee->loans as $loan){
            {{$employee->loan()->yourLoanAttribute}}
        }
    }
?>
```

Hope this help

Comment: As this is a one to many relationship, you won't get the LoanAttribute directly without looping the relationship.

Comment: exactly, this is only the excerpt. I assume @atymic already now how to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The name of your relation is `loan`.

Thus you can query it by using:

```php
$employee->loan // Instance of LoanRequest
```

Comment: i was calling loanRequest instead of loan but its work thanks there as was mistake Employee::with('loan')->get();

Answer (score 0):

```
public function loan() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LoanRequest','employee_id','loan_id');
}
```

Make sure column name is proper

```
Employee::with('loan')->get()
```

Will get All the employee with their load Relation